# How to create a Python function that has implicit reference to object whose function it's called in

Tags: python

Consider this example class of animal and the function fav_food:

```
def fav_food(qty):
    # function that should return a tuple of favourite food & quantity `qty`
    # passing animal instance as an argument is not an option
    # if(species == 'cat'): return ('tuna', qty)
    # if(species == 'mouse'): return ('cheese', qty)
    return ('dummyfood', qty)

class animal: 
    def __init__(self, name, weight, species):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.species = species        
    
    def eats(self, food):
        print(self.name + ' eats ' + food[0])
        self.weight = self.weight + food[1]
        print(self.name + '\'s new weight is: ' + str(self.weight))
    

tom = animal('tom', 5000, 'cat')
jerry = animal('jerry', 300, 'mouse')
tom.eats(fav_food(50)) # fav_food(50) should return ('tuna', 50) since tom is a cat
jerry.eats(fav_food(20)) # fav_food(20) should return ('cheese', 20) since jerry is a mouse
```

The above function calls give the following output:

```
tom eats dummyfood
tom's new weight is: 5050
jerry eats dummyfood
jerry's new weight is: 320
```

How to instead get the following output without passing tom/jerry to `fav_food`?:

```
tom eats tuna
tom's new weight is: 5050
jerry eats cheese
jerry's new weight is: 320
```

Comment: That is generally not possible and is nothing you EVER really want to do even if possible through very ugly hacks. Instead add a second parameter to `fav_food` which you then pass `tom` or `tom.species` into.

Comment: @luk2302 or just make `fav_food` class method of an object.

Comment: Yes, or add a class / enum for `Species` which has that functionality or various other possibilities, but certainly not the way OP wants.

Comment: I'm guessing (especially from constraints like *"passing animal instance as an argument is not an option"*) that you have a real-world problem with some specific nuances. It's probably better to say more about your real problem, because when it's described in "clean" animal/cat/dog terms, we're all going to give you "clean" solutions that might miss the actual constraints you have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the function a method of the class as suggested by
@matszwecja

`favourite_food` is clearly something that gives information about an animal, so from a design perspective it makes a lot of sense to make that function a method of the class Animal.

```
class Animal: 
    def __init__(self, name, weight, species):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.species = species        
    
    def eats(self):
        fav_food, qty = self.get_fav_food()
        print(f"{self.name} eats {fav_food}")
        self.weight += qty
        print(f"{self.name}'s new weight is: {str(self.weight)}")

    def get_fav_food(self):
        # returns a tuple of [favourite_food:string, quantity:int]
        fav_food = {
            "cat": ("tuna", 10), 
            "mouse": ("cheese", 5)
        }
        try:
            return fav_food[this.species]
        except KeyError:
            return ("dummyfood", 10)
```

Comment: `this.species` -> `self.species` :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, as Python is an interpreted language and has no information about the future, i.e., it doesn't know where the return value of a function will be used, and it doesn't need to. In the execution stack, `fav_food(...)` would be above `tom.eats(...)` which means `fav_food(...)` will be called first. If you want some context, pass it as a argument or use a method instead of a function.